# RegExp capturing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
#ud %+^'()=%^'K%J+^K$#££½6 u896%+& 547900
```

I want to capture this `#ud` in a first variable and anything else that comes after, in a second variable, but not including the first space.

PS: `#ud` can change to `#u64`, `#d` and etc.

How do I do it in a clean and simple way?

Comment: Something like `([^\s]+)\s?(.*)`? https://regex101.com/r/qM0hO1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/^(#[^ ]+) (.+)$/
```

I use the space character to find the end of the first part.

https://www.debuggex.com/r/VZcx0JLtfY4vNrzR

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to split the string:

```js
var re = /^(\S+)\s(.*)/; 
var str = '#ud %+^\'()=%^\'K%J+^K$#££½6 u896%+& 547900';
alert(str.split(re).filter(Boolean));
```

The `/(\S+)\s(.*)/` regex will match first characters that are not spaces with `(\S+)` and capture it, then the space, and then it captures the rest of the string. Capturing groups are necessary to add the texts to the resulting array. And the `.filter(Boolean)` function removes empty items from the array.